# LinePlot with Seaborn: View Limit Minimum Error

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```
    Month Year  Location    Revenue
0   2015-01     Location 1  0.00
1   2015-03     Location 1  1105.50
2   2015-04     Location 1  44034.28
3   2015-05     Location 1  56756.39
4   2015-06     Location 1  51502.22
```

There are about two years worth of data. There are 5 different locations. I want to create a lineplot with seaborn that shows 5 different lines (one for each location) with Revenue on the y-axis, Month Year on the x-axis.

```
sns.lineplot(x="Month Year", 
             y="Revenue", 
             hue="Location", 
             data=rev_by_month,
             palette="tab10")
```

When I run the code above, however, I receive the following error:

> view limit minimum -0.05500000000000001 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units

For the record, the Month Year column was created using the pandas .to_datetime() function.

Comment: Could you re-confirm that the `Month Year` column is actually the output of `pd.to_datetime`? To my knowledge, `pd.to_datetime` always returns a datetime object that includes days (and higher-res units), and never stops at year-month.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler - You're right I started with pd.to_datetime but later altered it using dt.to_period. Just sticking with the result set from pd.to_datetime doesn't help me here since the data is too granular. How can I graph this data at the monthly level?

Comment: The error message suggests that seaborn does not play nicely with `period` dtypes. I suggest using the output of `pd.to_datetime()`, which is `datetime64[ns]`, and plotting with that on the x-axis, even though that introduces a spurious day to each row.